# Apache Permission Denied (Permissions 755)

Tags: apache

I get the message:

```
Forbidden 
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Path of Apache is: /var/www. My configuration (/etc/apache2/{apache.conf, httpd.conf}) is correct because, in other times, was work. Permissions of folder /var/www is: 755.

The problem is: I removed home folder of root (/root) ant then I have this error...

File configuration of /sites-available/000-defaults:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Location /php/cron>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ip6-localhost 176.9.21.77
    Satisfy any
</Location>
```

Error Log of Apache:

> (13)Permission denied: /.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check
>   htaccess file, ensure it is readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the permissions in folder /etc/apache2/. We needed modify 744 level permissions to 755.